# GenericType of concrete class

Tags: java, generics

How can I get the generic Type from my concrete class. For example I have:

```
class MyClass<String>
{
 public Type getGenericType
 {
      // how can I return String.class in here?
 }
}
```

I can do that with abstract class like this:

```
abstract class MyClass<String>
{    
   public Type getGenericType
   {
     Type t = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
     return ((ParameterizedType)t).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
   }
}
```

How can I perform similar operation on the concrete class just like the abstract class. If I can't, can you explain me why?

Thanks,

Comment: Your example doesn't really make sense.  Is `String` a type parameter here or not?  Why choose "String" instead of something less likely to cause confusion?  By convention, type parameters are a single letter such as `E` or `T`.

Comment: You are right. Usually I will make String=T but i put it there for short and to illustrate my point.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, because once the code is compiled, generics **don't even exist** anymore.
Your `String` just becomes, effectively, `Object`.

That would obviously cause problems when your code is trying to run after compilation...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    private final Class<T> type;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyClass() {
       type = (Class<T>) this.getClass();
    }

    public Class<T> getGenericType() {
     return type;
    }

}
```

Comment: The constructor and member are doing nothing.  If that works, so too will `public Class<?> getGenericType() { return this.getClass(); }`

Answer (score 0):

At this stage Java does not support [reification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29) of generics. However, it is possible to get parameter type information at runtime for fields and methods. [This article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html) has a good insight into the matter. For classes it is often convenient to pass the parameter type into the constructor explicitly:

```
class ClassWithParameter<T> {
 private final Class<T> parameterType;

 public ClassWithParameter(final Class<T> parameterType) {
      this.parameterType = parameterType;
 }
 ... }
```

Alternatively, a custom runtime annotation with Class attribute could be created and used to annotate classes, which require parameter type information at runtime.